# Fixing FONTFORGE Open type font validation errors / TCPDF

Tags: php, encoding, tcpdf, fontforge

I am running into problems when preparing a custom OTF-font and AFM-file (Postscript type 1 resource) for PHP usage with TCPDF.

PHP programmatically the slots are not printed fontfontge has validation errors on, so i think my task is fixing the font with fontforge, but i don't know how to be honest.

Opening the source font with **fontforge** gives me the following validation-errors:

```
 The glyph named mu is mapped to U+00B5
  But It's name indicates it should be mapped to U+03BC
 The glyph named Delta is mapped to U+2206
  But It's name indicates it should be mapped to U+0394
 The glyph named fi is mapped to U+F001
  But It's name indicates it should be mapped to U+FB01
 The glyph named fl is mapped to U+F002
  But It's name indicates it should be mapped to U+FB02
```

Can you guys lend me a helping hand on this and make these characters "visible" for my PHP script?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i was a little mislead on tracking the error.
The validation errors still do occure, but i had to adjust my TCPDF object with

```
 $pdf->setFontSubsetting(false);
```

to prevent compacting the font.